# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'method'

Tags: python-3.x, list, class

I need to implement a stack class that will only store numbers
whole. Implement in this class a method that some the numbers
even and odd and return the division of the sum of the evens by the odds.
To add each number it is necessary to unstack a pile. At the
of this method, the stack will be empty. Here is my code:

```
import sys
import re

class Stack:


def __init__(self):
    self.stack=[] t
    self.size_stack = 0
    self.even=[] 
    self.odd=[] 
    
    
def stack(self, e):
    self.stack.append(e)
    self.size_stack +=1 

#método para remover e retornar o final da pilha    
def unstack(self):
    if self.void() == False:
        self.size_stack -=1 
        return self.stack.pop()            


def top(self):
    if self.void() == False:
        return self.stack[-1] 
    #return None


def void(self):
    if self.size_stack == 0 :
        return True
    return False


def size(self):
    return self.size_stack
   
def sum_stack(self):
    for num in self.stack:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            self.even.append(self.top)
            self.stack.pop()
        else:  
            self.odd.append(self.top)
            self.stack.pop()
            
    result_even = sum(self.even)
    result_odd = sum(self.odd)
    final_result = result_even/result_odd 
    return final_result
            

        
p = Stack()


n = int(input("Enter the number of digit to be entered: "))
for i in range(0, n):
    print("Type the ",i+1,'º number: ')
    inter = int(input())
    p.empilhar(inter)

       

print(p.final_result())
```

It gives me this error on result_even = sum(self.even): "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'method'"

Please help.

Comment: `self.even.append(self.top)` is adding a method (`self.top`) into `self.even`. Did you mean to call that method? (`self.even.append(self.top())`.

Comment: Also note that if inside of `top`, `self.void() == False` is False, `top` will implicitly return `None`, which will get placed into `self.evens`, which will cause a similar error as before.